# how to find the most appears one in a table using sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table A with two columns named B and C as following:

```
('W1','F2')
('W1','F7')
('W2','F1')
('W2','F6')
('W2','F8')
('W4','F7')
('W6','F2')
('W6','F15')
('W7','F1')
('W7','F4')
('W7','F17')
('W8','F13')
```

How can I find which one in the B column appears with the most time using sql in oracle? (In this case, it's W2 and W7). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery to calculate the number of items in columC for each value in columnB and `rank()` the results of the subquery based on that count. Then in your main select return just the values of columnB where the rank of the rows returned by the subquery is 1:

```
SELECT ColB
FROM (
       SELECT ColB,
              Count(ColC),
              rank() over (ORDER BY Count(ColC) DESC) AS rnk
       FROM yourTable
       GROUP BY ColB)
WHERE rnk = 1
```

Here's a sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fa6bd/2

Answer (score 1):

/*

1. C2 REFERS TO THE COLUMN B
2. T1 Refers to an alias

*/

WITH T1 AS
           (
           SELECT C2,COUNT(*) AS COUNT
           FROM YOURTABLE
           GROUP BY C2
           )

SELECT C2,COUNT FROM T1 WHERE COUNT=(SELECT MAX(COUNT) FROM T1 )
;

Answer (score 0):

```
Select ColB, Count(*) 
FROM yourTable 
GROUP BY ColB
ORDER BY count(*) desc
```